# In Rstudio, is there a way to get 'stargazer' to output variable containing decimals?

Tags: stargazer

When I use stargazer in Rstudio it doesn't output the variable ' median_income' from my dataset because it contains decimal values. It outputs the other variables that are 'integers' , however 'median_income' class type is 'character'. How do I get the output for median income through stargazer? please help thanks.
PS I am required to use stargazer to display the output .

Answer (score 0):

Convert character to numeric. This has nothing to do particular with `stargazer`.

```
mtcars$mpg <- as.character(mtcars$mpg)
stargazer(mtcars, type="text")

============================================
Statistic N   Mean   St. Dev.  Min     Max  
--------------------------------------------
cyl       32  6.188   1.786     4       8   
disp      32 230.722 123.939  71.100 472.000
hp        32 146.688  68.563    52     335  
drat      32  3.597   0.535   2.760   4.930 
wt        32  3.217   0.978   1.513   5.424 
qsec      32 17.849   1.787   14.500 22.900 
vs        32  0.438   0.504     0       1   
am        32  0.406   0.499     0       1   
gear      32  3.688   0.738     3       5   
carb      32  2.812   1.615     1       8   
--------------------------------------------

mtcars$mpg <- as.numeric(mtcars$mpg)
stargazer(mtcars, type="text")

============================================
Statistic N   Mean   St. Dev.  Min     Max  
--------------------------------------------
mpg       32 20.091   6.027   10.400 33.900 
cyl       32  6.188   1.786     4       8   
disp      32 230.722 123.939  71.100 472.000
hp        32 146.688  68.563    52     335  
drat      32  3.597   0.535   2.760   4.930 
wt        32  3.217   0.978   1.513   5.424 
qsec      32 17.849   1.787   14.500 22.900 
vs        32  0.438   0.504     0       1   
am        32  0.406   0.499     0       1   
gear      32  3.688   0.738     3       5   
carb      32  2.812   1.615     1       8   
--------------------------------------------
```